What is the syntax of JavaDocs comments & how can I generate the documentation page?
I know that javadoc comments use /** Comment */ instead of /* Comment */, and they has special tags like /** @param */. I know that javadoc comments are typically for users, while normal comments are for developers. However, I can't find a list of these tags and how they are used. I also can't figure out how I am expected to generate the documentation page once the javadoc comments are present. Sites just say "Use the javadoc tool". Where can I find it, how do I use it, how can the documentation be put on a permanent webpage like this page on ArrayLists, does the process change based on which IDE is being used?

You can get the list of the tags and their usage on this page on "How to write doc comments": https://www.oracle.com/ch-fr/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#tagcomments

You can find the javadoc tool in any JDK installation.  You can find the documentation in the JDK documentation; e.g. on the web - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/index.html

"Does the process change based on which IDE is being used?" - Assuming you are asking if you can generate javadocs in a Java IDE, yes you can.  And most Java build tools such as Maven, Ant, Gradle and so on also support this.  Just find and read the relevant documentation.

the official JDK documentation has a JavaDoc Guide, which links to Documentation Comment Tag Specification for the Standard Doclet
